# How is age defined in heaven?

Tags: catholicism, heaven, nature-of-man, resurrection-body

I am now older than what my father was when he passed away in 1967. Granted that both of us meet in heaven face to face, will his soul look younger than mine ? Is there any teaching available from the side of Catholic church to show that there is no eventuality of such ' embarrassing situation' in the life after death of the faithful ?

Comment: [A similar question.](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/38939/how-old-will-we-be-in-heaven)

Comment: On what basis do you presume time exists, or matters, in Heaven?