# Perfect life in heaven?

Tags: catholicism, heaven

Does the Catholic church teach that my life in heaven will always be "perfect", that is, I will want nothing more than what I have in my heavenly life because I will always be completely happy and completely satisfied with absolutely everything in my personal heavenly life?

Comment: Cf. This [answer of mine](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37004/what-is-heaven-like-according-to-catholics/37115#37115) to [What is Heaven like according to Catholics?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37004/what-is-heaven-like-according-to-catholics)